# Is this set of functions convex?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

$$
\alpha\leq f(t)\leq\beta,\quad \forall t\in[0,1]\\
f(0)=f_0,\quad f(1)=f_1
$$
where $f_0$ and $f_1\in[\alpha,\beta]$.

> Is the feasible set of $f$ convex in $f$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this question quite makes sense. Can you please express the set $\mathcal F(f)$ more clearly? In particular, in the first two lines, $f$ appears to be unbound.

Comment: Quantifiers! Is this one particular $t$ or all $t$ in $[0,1]$..  One particular value $f_0$ or all values $f_0$.  Etc.

Comment: @JohnHughes Sorry, now I update my question.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, now I update my question.

Comment: Can you say for us what it would mean for the set "to be convex in $f$"? I still don't know what you're talking about, but if you can ask the question in a simple enough form, maybe we can help you answer it. I guess I'm asking for two things: (1) What do you mean by "the feasible set", and (2) what does it mean to you that this set is convex? The latter should be an easily expressible notion, like "a set $F$ of functions from $\mathbb R$ to itself is called *convex* if for every $f \in F$, the graph of $f$ is either convex up or convex down." I'm sure that's not the def'n you mean. What is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is convex, for if $f_1,f_2,\dots f_n$ is any finite collection of functions in your "feasible set", and $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=1$ for some $\lambda_i\geq 0$, then the function $g(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if_i(t)$ clearly satisfies all the conditions:
$$\alpha\leq g(t)\leq \beta\enspace\forall t\in[0,1]\enspace\hbox{and} \enspace g(0)=f_0,\enspace g(1)=f_1$$
and so $g(t)$ also belongs to the "feasible set", so the latter is a convex set.

Comment: Your answer is great. I am a freshman on this area, can you give the right definition of my "feasible set of $f$"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh don't worry about it. It is perfectly OK, only a bit unusual. In order to avoid questions as you got above, you may want to use a more formal mathematical language, such as: Let $A$ be the set of all real-valued functions defined on $[0,1]$ for which the following properties hold: (list of your properties). Viewed as a subset of the vector-space of all real functions defined on $[0,1]$,  Is the set $A$ convex?  Such a formulation will avoid annoying questions, but then, being too formal can also be annoying...

Comment: It does help me! Thanks again.